# Ember ArrayController this.get doesn't work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having hard time to understand arrayController and ObjectController in Ember (at least I think this is the point.)
I'm working with an ArrayController and I need to get a model and modify it. (take today model and make in order to figured out how many days are in a month) but every time I do:

```
this.get("today")
```

nothing happen. Which from the documentation, that is how it should be call.

If I look at other example, most of the people use ObjectController, so i try it with that one too but I got an error complaining the #each loop i'm using need an ArrayController

Here is my code so far:

//Router

```
WebCalendar.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource("cal", {path: '/'});
        this.resource("location", {path: '/location'});
        this.resource("organization", {path: '/organization'});
    });
});

WebCalendar.CalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('dates');
    }
});
```

//Model

```
WebCalendar.Dates = DS.Model.extend({
    today: DS.attr('date'),
    month: DS.attr('date'),
    year: DS.attr('date'),
    daysName: DS.attr('array'),
    daysInMonth: DS.attr('array')
});


WebCalendar.Dates.FIXTURES = [
    {   
        id: 1,
        today: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'), 
        month: moment().format('MMM'),
        year: moment().format('YYYY'),
        daysName: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        daysInMonth: [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ]
    }
];
```

//CalController

```
WebCalendar.CalController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    getMonthDays: function(){
        return this.get("today");
    }.property('today')

});
```

//Cal Handlebars

```
<table>
    {{#each date in controller}}
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr id="year">
            <td>{{date.year}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prev-month"> Prev </td>
            <td id="month">{{date.month}}</td>
            <td id="next-month"> Next </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="days-of-week">
            {{#each date.daysName}}
                <td>{{this}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr class="days">
        <tr>{{getMonthDays}}</tr>
    </tbody>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

My questions are:

- Why this.get method doesn't work? Documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_get
- Is it correct that i'm using ArrayController in this specific situation?
- Why seems i cannot use #each loop with ObjectController?

Comment: Can we see the route including `model` and `setupController` hooks?

Comment: Yes, just added. I'm not using setupController instead store.find()

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{getMonthDays}}` is being invoked within the `{{each}}`, which means it is being called in the context of individual `Dates` objects, but you are defining it on the ArrayController--where Ember won't even look. You are confused between the ArrayController managing the collection of model instances, and individual model instances (or controllers therefor, which you haven't defined).

You need an **itemController**. I refer you to the documentation rather than summarizing it here. `getMonthDays` would be a method on the item controller.

By the way,

```
getMonthDays: function(){
    return this.get("today");
}.property('today')
```

is often better written as

```
getMonthDays: Ember.computed.alias('today')
```

or

```
getMonthDaysBinding: 'today'
```

Comment: "You are confused between the ArrayController managing the collection of model instances, and individual model instances (or controllers therefor, which you haven't defined)" Yes! I know I can do in the model but I thought isn't the right place where to do it.

Comment: getMonthDays display just 'today' because I was testing if i can display something or not, but the idea is to write a function which find all the days in a month in order to display them in my little calendar

Comment: nice thank you. I try now. Question: Why you said itemController can be complicated? And thanks for the better way to write it but i always wonder why there are so many things in Ember which are not documented or not easy to find out..